# Convert ForeignCollection to ArrayList - ORMLite, Gson and Android

Tags: android, arraylist, gson, ormlite, foreign-collection

I apologize if I'm not super clear with my explanation but I'll add to and edit this question for clarity if requested.

I am developing an Android app which receives data through an external API and stores data locally using ORMLite. Prior to storing data locally and using ORMLite I had models which retrieved JSON from the server and parsed it via:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

String result = ApiClient.httpPost("/user_route");

User user = gson.fromJson(result, User.class);
```

The User class was defined

```
public class User {
  int id;
  String name;
  ArrayList<Image> media;
}
```

And the Image class:

```
public class Image {
  int id;
  int creator_id;
  String url;
}
```

This is a simplified representation of the models and methods but I believe I've kept all the relevant information. BTW, `media` is a JSON object which contains the `Images`.

Now I'm trying to also store the data locally. In order to have the relationship between Users and Images using ORMLite it seems you have to employ ForeignCollection class and @ForeignCollectionField annotation. I don't believe Gson can directly parse the Json for the `media` field in the User class as a ForeignCollection object, so I thought I needed to create two fields `mediaCollection` and `media`.

Using ORMLite the User class now looks like this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Users")
public class User {
  @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
  int id;

  @DatabaseField
  String name;

  @ForeignCollectionField
  ForeignCollection<Image> mediaCollection;

  ArrayList<Image> media;
}
```

The Image class with ORMLite looks like this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Images")
public class Image {

  @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
  int id;

  @DatabaseField(foreign=true, foreignAutoCreate=true, foreignAutoRefresh=true)
  private User user;

  @DatabaseField
  int creator_id;

  @DatabaseField
  String url;

}
```

How the flow of the app works is first I hit the local database for a User. I perform some logic which then determines if I need to actually hit the server to 'update' or 'refresh' the User data.

Whether the data comes locally or from the remote server, I need to display the `Image` in the same view. As it stands now, the URL for the `Image` is stored in different types of objects depending on whether the data is local or remote. What I would like to do is if the `Image` is stored in a `ForeginCollection` object, convert that object into an `ArrayList` and then proceed with the rest of my code which extracts the `Image` URL and displays it.

I guess there are two questions.

1. Is this a good plan or should I write two completely separate ways of extracting the `Image` URL from the data, NOT converting the object from `ForeignCollection` to `ArrayList`?
2. If it *is* a good plan, how do I convert a `ForeginCollection` to an `ArrayList`?

Comment: see answer in another related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31598771/3495371

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Is this a good plan or should I write two completely separate ways of extracting the Image URL from the data, NOT converting the object from ForeignCollection to ArrayList?

It should work.  I don't see an easy way to do it otherwise.

Some points:

- Is there some way to mark the `ForeignCollection` as transient so it is ignored when transferring over JSON?  Then you can use the same `User` object for both JSON and ORMLite.
- Some sort of `hydrate()` method would be good so it would convert from `media` -> `mediaCollection` and vice versa.
- If you need to load JSON transferred images into the foreign collection then you should use the [`Dao.getEmptyForeignCollect(...)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#getEmptyForeignCollection%28java.lang.String%29) method.  Once you have the collection, you can add images into it and they will be added to the tables.

> If it is a good plan, how do I convert a ForeignCollection to an ArrayList?

This is easier. A `ForeignCollection` is a `Collection`. You can just do a:

```
media = new ArrayList<Image>(mediaCollection);
```

So your `User.getMedia()` method should check for `null` and if so, convert from the `mediaCollection` field.

Comment: Can you expand on the conversion from a `ForeignCollection`? I'm trying to obtain an array using `Image[] media = mediaCollection.toArray(new Image[0])` but this throws  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase [...]` stemming from `LazyForeignCollection:232`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to Convert from `@ForeignCollectionField` to `ArrayList<Object>`
you can do that:

```
ArrayList<Object> taskFieldsList = new ArrayList<Object>(your collection);
```

hope it's help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a ForeignCollection other than first storing the objects in the database, then have ormlite retrieve them in the ForeignCollection. You can use a Collection instead of a ForeignCollection, but it works the same way. What I do is the following: I have two collections in the parent class. One is an ArrayList that the json or xml is deserialized into. When the parent object gets stored, the dao stores the objects in the Arraylist to the database, in the table that's linked to the other Collection, a ForeignCollection. When the parent object is retrieved, it automatically contains the objects in the ForeignCollection. It's not perfect, but it works.

Comment: This is somewhat incorrect. You can get a new `ForeignCollection` by using the `Dao.getEmptyForeignCollection(...)` method.  See here: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#getEmptyForeignCollection(java.lang.String%29