# Jackson can't deserialize to a ForeignCollection (Ormlite)

Tags: java, android, jackson, ormlite

I've have issues deserializing nested json data. I am using Ormlite to persist the data and a combination of Spring/Jackson(2) to fetch the data. Collections/lists of objects must be of the `ForeignCollection` interface before Ormlite will persist it. I've read several other Stackoverflow posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853324/can-not-find-deserialize-for-non-concrete-collection-type), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699190/convert-foreigncollection-to-arraylist-ormlite-gson-and-android), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100744/exception-while-using-jackson-and-ormlite-annotations-together-in-one-object)), but non of them has a clear solution.

Here is some of my code:

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
@JsonProperty("images")
private ForeignCollection<Image> images;
```

I've tried adding `@JsonDeserialize(as=BaseForeignCollection.class)` without any luck. Changing `ForeignCollection` to `Collection` will make Jackson happy and parse the data, but then it won't hit the database.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not got access to the android libs or the `@ForeignCollectionFields`. If I interpret your problem correctly you have trouble deserializing the `ForeignCollection` as a *normal* collection. You can *force* the behaviour of Jackson deserialization by the `@JsonFormat` annotation. So, what happens if you add this to your field?  `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)`

Comment: Can you please provide your parent and child model class

Answer (score 0):

ForeignCollection is an interface, so serialization will not be possible. You should use a class implementing it, or just @JsonIgnore that field and add a regular List just for serialization/deserialization purposes.